# Are parameter estimates in GLMs ever consistent?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, consistency, misspecification

Given that parameter estimates in GLMs are inconsistent if any of

a) errors are heteroscedastic

b) link function is misspecified

c) covariates are not included

d) (other conditions?)

happen to apply (and they are likely to apply in any real problem), what good are such estimates and the models that use them?

**Add 1**

Given that the estimates are likely to be inconsistent, is there a way to assess the degrees of that inconsistency? That is, if the estiamte converges to $\beta_1 \ne \beta_0$ (with $\beta_0$ being the true value), how different is $\beta_1$ from $\beta_0$? Is there a way to assess this difference / put some bounds on it?

**Add 2**

Greene states in "Econometric Analsis" (5th ed., p673) "[...] maximum likelihood estimator is not consistent in the presence of any form of heteroscedasticity, unmeasured heterogeneity, omitted variables (even if they are orthogonal to the included ones) [...]", and since GLMs are estimated using MLEs, it seems to imply that they are bound to produce inconsistent esitmates.

Comment: The american insurance industry rakes in billions of dollars a year built on the foundation of GLMs.  They must have something going for them.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? As presently stated, I believe it's not correct. Most GLMs are heteroskedastic even when correctly specified. I'd be interested to see exactly what was claimed and how it was proved in relation to (a). Items (b) and (c) (or equivalents) apply to a huge variety of statistical models (including regression), not just to GLMs, so if those concern you, you should be wary of a lot more than GLMs.

Comment: I think that this will be trivially true for parameters, but not necessarily for marginal effects

Comment: This question seems like a complicated way to ask "if our models aren't completely correct, why are they any good at all?"  After all, consistency is an asymptotic property and "inconsistency" has no quantitative meaning, implying in any actual situation an inconsistent estimator might very well be an excellent one.

Comment: @whuber That is, in a sense, a part of a question: if an estimator is not consistent, how good / bad is it? PS. What do you mean by inconsistency not having any quantitative meaning?

Comment: *Consistency* has a clear meaning: asymptotically, an estimator converges to the value of its estimand. "Inconsistency" could mean anything else. For instance, the estimator could converge to within one part in $10^{100}$ of its correct value, or it could be extremely close to its correct value for all sample sizes less than $10^{10}$ and then diverge, or it could converge in all but one exceptional state of nature. This shows that "inconsistent" doesn't mean much: it's important to specify *how* an estimator fails to be consistent and by *how much.*

Comment: @whuber Is there a way to assess by how much one's estimate (i.e. for any given model) my be "inconsistent"? Does it depend on what leads to the estimator not being consistent (e.g. excluded covariates, heteroscedastisity, etc)? Are you able / willing to expand it into an answer?